# add alias email with office 365 small business premuim

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, central-administration, exchange

In the past few days, we were able to add alias email for a primary email , but now the icons for add alias email is hidden , so we can't add an alias email 
Why this icons is hidden for us ?
Is there any way to do it in admin page ?

thanks in advance
[image]